# How to replace website?

Tags: plugins, blog, backup

I have a current Wordpress website under domain.com and working (nearly finished) website under test.domain.com

**What would be the best method to replace the old (domain.com) website with the new version of it (test.domain.com)?**

I also want to keep the old (domain.com) blog postings and their associated media files.

Comment: It seems like you just need to upload the new theme and plugins to the old website.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the **All-in-One WP Migration** to make a backup of the new test site. Then install the plugin in your old site as well and upload the backup there. 
Then update the permalinks and change Site URL in Setting > General if needed.

Here's the URL for the Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/